# react native component has no access to props - TypeError: Cannot read property ‘navigation’ of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvaBL.png)

TypeError: Cannot read property ‘navigation’ of undefined? 
Looks like my component has no access to this.props.navigation.( react-navigation) 
Basically I get this error whenever I call: const { navigate } = this.props.navigation.

Any idea how to give the component access to this.props.navigation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 classes don't autobind `this`. There's a few solutions to this like binding in the constructor or just changing it to an arrow function:

```
renderRow = ({ item }) => {
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Got it, you just resolved my issue. A million thanks